# python generators time complexity confusion

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity, generator

I have been reading about keyword `yield` and generators in python and I want to know if I have understood it right it terms of time complexity.

Here is my generator function to get factors:

```
def calc_factors(n):
    for k in range(0, n+1):     # this is the second "for" loop
        if n % k == 0:
           yield k
```

and I would call this generator function as:

```
>>> for factor in calc_factor(100):   # this is the first "for" loop
        print factor
```

Now my understanding is that this has time complexity of O(n^2) as it has two for loops but again I'm not convinced. Please enlighten me on this front.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't just count the loops in your program and stick the count next to n^. Time complexity doesn't work that way.

Comment: While syntactically, you have two loops, only one iteration of the loop in the generator executes for each iteration of the loop outside the generator. The total amount of time spent is proportional to n, not n^2.

Comment: @user2357112 : Thanks for your comment. I was confused as it appeared like first `for` loop executes then it'll call the generator function but then generator function has another `for` loop which made me think so. I agree counting `for` loops is not right way to judge the time complexity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstood. You have a O(n) loop. The loop over the generator function is *not* a nested loop, it merely receives each item from the generator as it is yielded.

In other words, the `for factor in calc_factor(100)` loop is *directly connected* to the `yield k` expression; each time that executes the `for factor in calc_factor(100)` loop advances one step. You get 1 `factor` value for every `yield k` expression executed. `yield k` executes (up to) `n` times, no more.

You can, without bending the truth too much, imagine all code in the `for factor in calc_factor(100)` loop body as *replacing* the `yield k` line, with `factor = k`. In your case you only use `print factor`, so you could replace the `yield k` with `print k` with no loss of functionality.

If you want to look at it differently, take away the generator and build a list. This is what your code does in that case:

```
results = []
for k in range(0, n+1):
    if n % k == 0:
       results.append(k)

for factor in results:
    print factor
```

Now you have two loops still, but they are not nested. One is a O(n) loop to build the list, the other is a O(k) loop (with k < n) to print the results. This would still be a O(n) algorithm; constant multipliers are ignored (you'd have O(2n) -> O(n)).

All the generator does is *remove the intermediary list*. You don't have to first collect all the results, you get to have access to each result immediately.

Comment: so the `for` loop inside the `calc_factor(n)` is not considered ?

Comment: @d-coder: of course it is. But the loop *over* the generator results is not a new loop. You don't run *all* of the loop in `calc_factor()` each time you step to the next result (which would make it n**2), you step through all the results of the generator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your answer cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

No, this should only have time complexity O(n).

In a true nested loop, *every* iteration of the outer loop causes a *full* set of iterations of the inner loop:

```
for i in range(100):      # 100 times
    for j in range(i):    # i times, for *each* of the 100 values of i
         # do something
```

But in a generator, a `yield` statement causes an *immediate* return of control from the generator. So each time the generator is iterated only counts as *one* pass through the generator's loop.

So your `for factor in calc_factor(100):` invokes the generator *once per instance of the generator's loop*. So in a sense, this *is* the generator's loop; it's just controlled from outside the generator itself. It is therefore *not* an outer *nested* loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I got my confusion cleared.