# Python generator time complexity log(n)

Tags: python, time-complexity, generator, space-complexity

In python3 range built with help of generators

Logarithmic Time — O(log n)
An algorithm is said to have a logarithmic time complexity when it reduces the size of the input data in each step. example if we are printing first 10 digits with help of generators first we will get one element so remaining 9 element has to process,  then second element so remaining 8 element has to process

```
for index in range(0, len(data)):
    print(data[index])
```

When i check the url [python generators time complexity confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400755/python-generators-time-complexity-confusion) its saying  O(n).

Since every time its generating only one output because we need to do `__next__`
it will be everytime 1 unit cost.

Can I get explanation on this

Comment: Where did you get that definition of logarithmic time from? It’s incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That explanation of logarithmic time complexity is wrong.

You get logarithmic complexity if you reduce the size of the input by a fraction, not by a fixed amount. For instance, binary search divides the size by 2 on each iteration, so it's O(log n). If the input size is `8` it takes `4` iterations, doubling the size to `16` only increase iterations to `5`.